# Datos de un array de php a una tabla html

Tags: php, html

Como paso los datos de un arreglo de php a una tabla html? aqui les dejo mi codigo, esta es la informacion que obtengo de una encuesta a varias personas, son tres archivos, pero esto me funciona bien, lo que no puedo hacer es que la informacion sea presentada en una tabla, tengo un problema con el foreach, solo me muestra los codigos, se que tengo un error con el foreach, pero no se como solucionar el problema.

```
            <?php
                
                $cant=$_POST['can']; //obtengo los datos del formulario
                 $datosnom=array();//datos de los nombres
                 $datoscod=array();//datos de los codigos
                 $datosed=array();//datos de las edades 
                 $datosop=array();//datos de la opcion a elegir de la pregunta 1
                 $datosopc=array();//datos a elegir de la pregunta 2 
                //para recorrer el vector de los nombres
    
                echo "<h3>Estadistica para ".$cant.""." Estudiantes</h3><hr>";
                 for($i=0;$i<$cant;$i++){
                     $pos1="nom".($i);
                     $datosnom[$i]=$_POST[$pos1];
                     echo $datosnom[$i]."<br>";             
                 }
                 //para recorrer el vector de los codigos
                 for($i=0;$i<$cant;$i++){
                    $pos2="cod".($i);
                    $datoscod[$i]=$_POST[$pos2];
                    echo $datoscod[$i]."<br>";             
                }
                //para recorrer el vector de las edades
                $suma=0;
                for($i=0;$i<$cant;$i++){
                    $pos3="ed".($i);
                    $datosed[$i]=$_POST[$pos3];
                    $suma=$suma+$datosed[$i];
                    echo $datosed[$i]."<br>";             
                }
    
                echo "la suma es :".$suma."<br>";
                echo "la media de las edades".($suma/$cant)."<br>";
                
                //para recorrer el vector de la opcion de la pregunta 1
                for($i=0;$i<$cant;$i++){
                    $pos4="op".($i);
                    $datosop[$i]=$_POST[$pos4];
                    echo $datosop[$i]."<br>";             
                }
                //para recorrer el vector de la opcion de la pregunta 2
                for($i=0;$i<$cant;$i++){
                    $pos5="opc".($i);
                    $datosopc[$i]=$_POST[$pos5];
                    echo $datosopc[$i]."<br>";             
                }
               // lo que quiero es mostrar toda la informacion un una tabla 
            ?>
    
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Codigo</th>
                    <th>Nombres</th>
                    <th>Edad</th>
                    <th>Calidad Sincronos</th>
                    <th>Calidad Asincronos</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($datoscod as $key => $cod) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $cod;?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado, te recomiendo guardar la información proveniente de las variables `$_POST` en un solo arreglo (`array`), de esa manera el recorrido del `foreach` se realiza con mayor facilidad. La propuesta es la siguiente:

```
<?php

$cant = $_POST['can']; //obtengo los datos del formulario

$datos = array(); //Solo indicamos el uso de un solo arreglo

//para recorrer el vector de los nombres
echo "<h3>Estadistica para " . $cant . " Estudiantes</h3><hr>";

for ($i = 0; $i < $cant; $i++) {
    $pos = "nom".$i; //por lo que veo nombre del input
    $datos[$i]['nombre'] = $_POST[$pos];
    echo $datos[$i]['nombre'] . "<br>";
}

//para recorrer el vector de los codigos
for ($i = 0; $i < $cant; $i++) {
    $pos = "cod".$i;
    $datos[$i]['codigo'] = $_POST[$pos];
    echo $datos[$i]['codigo'] . "<br>";
}
//para recorrer el vector de las edades
$suma = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $cant; $i++) {
    $pos = "ed".$i;
    $datos[$i]['edad'] = $_POST[$pos];
    $suma = $suma + $datos[$i]['edad'];
    echo $datos[$i]['edad'] . "<br>";
}

echo "la suma es :" . $suma . "<br>";
echo "la media de las edades" . ($suma / $cant) . "<br>";

//para recorrer el vector de la opcion de la pregunta 1
for ($i = 0; $i < $cant; $i++) {
    $pos = "op".$i;
    $datos[$i]['pregunta1'] = $_POST[$pos];
    echo $datos[$i]['pregunta1'] . "<br>";
}

//para recorrer el vector de la opcion de la pregunta 2
for ($i = 0; $i < $cant; $i++) {
    $pos = "opc".$i;
    $datos[$i]['pregunta2'] = $_POST[$pos];
    echo $datos[$i]['pregunta2'] . "<br>";
}
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Nombres</th>
        <th>Edad</th>
        <th>Calidad Sincronos</th>
        <th>Calidad Asincronos</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($datos as $key => $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $value['codigo']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $value['nombre']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $value['edad']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $value['pregunta1']; //Supongo que la pregunta 1, tiene algo que ver con la columna ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $value['pregunta2']; //Supongo que la pregunta 2, tiene algo que ver con la columna  ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

</table>
```

Como estas recorriendo los `for` con una cantidad fija, vamos poniendo en cada posición (las cuales serian las filas) los atributos (las claves que utilizamos como columnas) que luego queremos obtener.

Comment: Buena respuesta y muy bien explicada